# SOAPUI: how to refer to external jars?

Tags: jar, dependencies, soapui

Commonly known, that for usage of different jars we need add them to SoapUI/../ext/ directory. for example, for correct work of jdbc requests with IBM/..AS400JDBC Driver we need to add jt400.jar to /ext dir.
But I have problem: my client implements new policy - direct forbidding of using any jars locally, only as dependencies like

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jt400</groupId>
    <artifactId>jt400-full</artifactId>
    <version>6.0</version>
 </dependency>
```

I successfully uses it in my POM's for CI, but I also need to run my projects in SOAPUI.

So, question is: is there any way to add dependency for external jars, - exists in SoapUI preferences somewhere/somehow? Goal is to remove all jars from soapui/../ext and somehow add dependencies on official.

Sincerely,
Dmitry.

Comment: Have a read through `%SOAPUI_HOME%\bin\soapui.bat`. You will find that is very difficult to sneak in an additional dependency from elsewhere. I found that running `%SOAPUI_HOME%\bin\soapui.exe`, which you get from the launch menu, is even more restrictive! For example: it does not even care about your `JAVA_HOME`.

Answer (score 0):

I have thought about this some more: You should be able to roll your own `soapui.bat`, based on the provided one.

1. Copy the provided `soapui.bat` to your desktop.
2. Modify the variable `SOAPUI_HOME` to point to your install.
3. Modify the variable `CLASSPATH` to include your jars.
4. Run the modified `soapui.bat`.